# Cucumber JS timeout won't work

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs

Using the `protractor-cucumber-framework`, I'm trying to click a button a hundred times in one When-step. However, doing this would result in a timeout with the default 5000ms timeout value. I'd rather not change this default using:

```
var config = function() {
    this.setDefaultTimeout(60*1000);
};

module.exports = config;
```

This works, but I would rather set the timeout for that single step like so:

```
this.When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" button$/, {timeout: 60*1000}, function(text, callback)
{
    // Click the button 100 times
    var button = element(by.partialButtonText('Widget'));
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        button.click();
    }
    callback();
});
```

According to the [cucumber-js readme](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#timeouts) this *should* work, but still results in:

```
Error: Step timed out after 5000 milliseconds
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timer.js:92:15)
```

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

EDIT: It *did* work. However, I was using it in the wrong step. Calling `click()` a hundred times doesn't take so long. It times out on the step after it:

```
this.Then(/^a new widget is created$/, {timeout: 60 * 1000}, function(callback) {
    // Check if 100 widgets are created
});
```

Can anyone explain now why the long timeout is necessary in the step *after* all the calls to `click`? Is there a more elegant way to have cucumber wait for the buttonclicks to finish?

Comment: The documentation you linked to shows the `Given` function, not `When`.  I'm not a cucumber expert, but in the little bit of digging I've done I haven't been able to find anything that indicates that `When` will accept the timeout in the manner you are trying to use.

Comment: I edited my question. It does work but not in the way I expected. I think someone with more cucumber expertise is needed to answer my question as I'm still confused why it works the way it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the timeout doesn't work for you as expected is that your `callback()` is fired early, even before the completion of the first `click()`. This is because the `click()`s are asynchronous and are added to protractor's `controlFlow` (they get queued to be fired one after the other), but the `callback()` is not. There are a couple of options to avoid this.

### Option #1

You should make sure that the `callback()` is only fired once all the promises returned by `click()`s are fulfilled.

You can collect all the promises returned and call your `callback()` once all of them are resolved. This is what you would want to do if you did not know of the `controlFlow`:

```
this.When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" button$/, {timeout: 60*1000}, function(text, callback)
{
    // Click the button 100 times
    var button = element(by.partialButtonText('Widget'));
    var promises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        promises.push(button.click());
    }

    protractor.promise.all(promises).then(callback);
});
```

### Option #2

But things can get much easier if you just stash your `callback()` onto the `controlFlow` queue like this:

```
this.When(/^I click on the "([^"]*)" button$/, {timeout: 60*1000}, function(text, callback)
{
    // Click the button 100 times
    var button = element(by.partialButtonText('Widget'));
    for(var i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        button.click();
    }

    browser.controlFlow().execute(callback);
});
```

As you can see, when working with Protractor you should make use of its `controlFlow` to avoid writing asynchronous (looking) code.